# Writing and Reading to a Json format

Tags: c#, javascript, json

I have a large object in C# that i would like to write (serialize) to a .json file. I then want to read this .json file and be able to deserialize this object in javascript in order to display it on a website (after formatting it further in javascript). Can anyone tell me how i can achieve this serialization and deserialization to and from a properly formatted json file? Ive tried a few approaches but cant seem to achieve a tree like object structure in outputted file.

Thanks

Comment: Just google for `DataContractJsonSerializer`, `JavaScriptSerializer`, `Json.Net` etc.

Comment: If you are using Asp.Net MVC, you can use the built in JsonResult class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a WebService you can set the [ScriptService] tag on your methods.  If you are in a winforms or some other kind of app and need to use just serialize an object, you can tag your class serializable and then you can use the JavaSciptSerializer:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClas
{
    public int intVal { get; set; }
    public double doubleVal { get; set; }
    public string stringVal { get; set; }
}
```

In a method:

```
// Add a reference to System.Web.Extensions
// using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var myClass = new MyClas();
myClass.doubleVal = 42.00;
myClass.intVal = 42;
myClass.stringVal = "The answer";
MessageBox.Show(jss.Serialize(myClass));
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSON Lint](https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint) could be what you're looking for on the client end. It's a pure javascript json validator/reformatter.

You can test the library [here](http://zaach.github.com/jsonlint/). It takes:

```
{"example" : "of", "json" : ["being", "reformatted"], "into" : {"something" : "pretty"}}
```

and makes it:

```
{
  "example": "of",
  "json": [
    "being",
    "reformatted"
  ],
  "into": {
    "something": "pretty"
  }
}
```

Comment: in question: `I have a large object in` **`C#`** `that i would like to write (serialize) to a .json file.`